# If a block device has a permission of brwx______, how secure is it?

Tags: permissions, devices, block-device

I have trouble finding information on what permissions for block devices really mean. For block devices, what does read permission mean? Does it mean I can't do stuff like hexdump? What about write permission? Or execute?

And additionally, what if you have mount permission on the device by giving a user sudo permission to mount only that particular device, but not r,w,or x permissions on the device. What will happen then?

Comment: 'r' means read, 'w' means write and 'x' means executable like any other file. 'b' indicates it is a block device.

Answer (score 1):

For the simple cases (when you access the device like a file) it's as @Jasen wrote:

- The read permission allows reading from the device (dumping, running `fsck` in read-only mode, etc.)
- The write permission allows writing to the device (overwriting with an image, etc.)
- Both permissions are needed to run `fsck`, `tune2fs`, etc. which need to read *and* modify the filesystem.
- The execute permission is ignored. If you try to execute a device file you'll get 'Permission denied' even if the block device contains valid executable code.

If you are root you usually get the `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` and `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), which means that the permission flags are completely ignored.

For **ioctls** it's more complicated:

To perform an ioctl, you need to be able to *open* the file, which means that at least you need read or write permission.

Everything else is driver-dependent.
Some device drivers only check for capabilities like `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` or `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`, some use the read permission for "harmless" ioctls, that only provide information and the read+write permission for other ioctls. A device driver might use the execute permission for an ioctl permission check, but I don't know of any driver that does this.

For **mount** it's easier:

The `mount` syscall only checks for two things:

1. You need to be able to *reach* the device file.
   This means that all directories on the path to the device file need to have at least the execute permission bit set (or you need have the `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` capability).
2. You need to have the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability (which again you usually get when you are root)

The permission bits on the device file itself are completely ignored for mounting and have no influence on the access to the mounted filesystem in any way.

Using **sudo** runs the executed program as root with all available capabilities, which means that all permission checks are ignored
and as @Jasen wrote in a comment, `/bin/mount` is usually setuid-root, which causes it to always get all available capabilities, so permission bits have no influence on `mount` on most Linux distributions *and other unixoid operating systems*.

**EDIT:** the parts about capabilities are Linux specific. Other unixoid operating systems like BSD or OSX don't separate root's special abilities into capabilities, so when capabilites are mentioned, you simply need to be root. Based on the available manpages the checks for `mount` are similar to the Linux specific checks I described. There doesn't seem to be an OS that checks the permission bits when mounting.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice the OP didn't mention a specific os. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

read allows reading (eg hexdump)
write allows writing (eg writing an image to the device)
in combination this mean you can use a tool like "hexedit" to view and modify the content.

I don't know what x allows, (possibly it allows ioctl?)

as the permissions are `brwx______` that means only the owner (typically `root`) can do those things.

Comment: I suspect the execute permission has no meaning at all on device files.

Comment: I have an additional question to this then. What if one is given mount permission for the device but doesn't have read or write permissions?

Comment: permission how?   `/bin/mount`  is setuid to root so it can mount anything. it checks /etc/fstab to see if 'user' is listed in options.  `udev`, if your system uses that  also runs as root and can mount things too.

Comment: Isn't it possible to give a user permission to mount only a specific disk with sudo?

Comment: yeah, sudo is yet another way,  sudo basically makes you root for the command it launches.

Comment: Yeah, so I was wondering if the user has sudo permission to mount only that device but the device also has permissions settings, what can the user do?

Comment: @CuriousKimchi, if the user has sudo permission to mount the device he will be able to mount the device.  If he doesn't have any other root permissions from sudo then he won't be able to do any other root-only actions.  Simple enough.

Comment: Here's an example: A person has sudo privilege to mount `/dev/foo` and calls `mount /dev/foo /mnt/foo`. But this person does not have rwx permission on the device. Couple scenarios I can think of: 1. Mount fails because of the rwx permission. 2. Mount succeeds but you cannot `cd` into the directory. 3. You can `cd` into the directory, but you can't `ls`. 4. You can `cd` and `ls`, but you can't view the file. Which of these relate to which of "r, w, x" and are there other effects of "r, w, x" that I need to know?

Comment: @CuriousKimchi those actions are controlled by RWX and ownership on the mount-point, and also any RWX  provided by the new filesystem itself.